# Event fire twice

Tags: javascript, jquery, events

Upon request, the button to click, to fire the event is the wide-ass orange button

this fire is suppose to add 12 vh to the height of #pfcontainer_inner_friends_list, and then upon 2nd click remove the height again

By the way; I'm not looking for a solution that does not entail ADDING or SUBTRACTING the height. The height of the element has to stay on 10.2vh, and the fires, HAVE TO, add or subtract a given height.

http://jsfiddle.net/zy73nd2c/

In the fiddle above, I've tried showcasing how my jQuery is firing twice upon click. How do i fix this?

```
$(function () {
$('.click-nav1 > ul').toggleClass('no-js js');
$('.clicker1').click(function (e) {
    $('.click-nav1 .js ul').slideToggle(200);
    $('.clicker1').toggleClass('active');
    e.stopPropagation(); 
});
$('.clicker1').click(function () {
    if ($('.click-nav1 .js ul').is(':visible')) {
        $('.click-nav1 .js ul', this).slideUp();
        $('.clicker1').removeClass('active');
    }
});
});
$(function () {
$('.clicker1').click(function () { 
   if ($('.click-nav1 .js ul').is(':visible')) {
       $("#pfcontainer_inner_friends_list ul").animate({"height" :      "+=12vh"});}
});
});
$(function () {
$('.clicker1').click(function () { 
   if ($('.click-nav1 .js ul').is(':hidden')) {
       $("#pfcontainer_inner_friends_list ul").animate({"height" : "-    =12vh"});}
});
});
```

Comment: What is supposed to happen? The fiddle does not show anything on any click: So where to click (a button in the fiddle or text with "Click here" could help a lot). What happens twice (something with "result" clearly marked)?

Comment: Sorry my bad! I've updated the question.

Comment: Logged:      
  console.log("1: "+$('.click-nav1 .js ul').is(':hidden'));
       console.log("2: "+$('.click-nav1 .js ul').is(':visible'));

Both return true. So the event does not seem to be the issue, your check on when yo show/hide however is. You can set an attribute yourself, which is more safe then this method.

Comment: which event is firing twice?

Comment: NORBERT VAN NOBELEN, Could you ellaborate?

Comment: VIM, well not ONE event. But i've got two events coded into the jqeury, that will respectively add or subtract height to the ul element. I need them both to fire upon a click on the orance button, in two states that is!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently, `.is(":visible")` and `.is(":hidden")` can have the same value at a certain time of evaluation.

Possible work-around:
Toggle a class on the $element of choice, then use `$element.hasClass(...)` to decide whether to increase or decrease height.

This works as js in your jsfiddle:

```
$(function () {
    $('.click-nav1 > ul').toggleClass('no-js js');
    $('.clicker1').click(function (e) {
        $('.click-nav1 .js ul').toggleClass('vis').slideToggle(200);
        $('.clicker1').toggleClass('active');
        e.stopPropagation(); 
    });
    $('.clicker1').click(function () {
        if ($('.click-nav1 .js ul').is(':visible')) {
            $('.click-nav1 .js ul', this).slideUp();
            $('.clicker1').removeClass('active');
        }
    });
    $('.clicker1').click(function () {
        var dh = $('.click-nav1 .js ul').hasClass('vis') ? "+=12vh" : "-=12vh";
        $("#pfcontainer_inner_friends_list ul").animate({"height" : dh});
    });
});
```

Comment: Thank you very much, can't beleive I missed the toggle class workaround. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Instead of checking `.is(':visible')` check `.height()`:

```
$('.clicker1').click(function () { 
    if ($('.click-nav1 .js ul').height()>1) {
        $("#pfcontainer_inner_friends_list ul").animate({"height" : "+=12vh"});
    }else{
        $("#pfcontainer_inner_friends_list ul").animate({"height" : "-=12vh"});
    }
});
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/zy73nd2c/3/